# "Kiss him, Liesel. Kiss him" in "The Book Thief"

Tags: markus-zusak, the-book-thief

On page 454/455 of *The Book Thief*, in The Anarchist's Suit Collection at the end of Part Eight, Liesel is leaning over her adolescent boyfriend, Rudy Steiner. This line appears:

> Kiss him, Liesel. Kiss him

There are no quotation marks. Is this a thought of hers? Is she speaking this very softly? Some have said it is Death whispering in her ears.